# com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation PHP-Laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, firebase

I was using "kreait/firebase-php" to generate Firebase Custom token in Laravel. My code to generate Custom Token is as follows:

```
public function getToken(){

    $user = Auth::user();

    $serviceAccount=ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/service_account.json');

    $firebase = (new Factory)
                ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
                ->create();

    $customToken=$firebase->getAuth()->createCustomToken("id");

    return response()->json(["custom_token"=>$customToken]);
}
```

I am getting JWT token without any problem. But when I try to signIn using this token in android I get token format incorrect error. My Android Code is as Follows :

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("SignIn", "signInWithCustomToken:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Log.e("current User is",user.getUid());
                    } else {

                        Log.w("Sign iN failed", "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       /// updateUI(null);
                    }
                }
            });
```

And Logcat output is :

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwn.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxx.zzap(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdya.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxo.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

Please help me to resolve this error. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/179

Comment: return response()->json(["custom_token"=>(string)$customToken]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated custom token is an instance of `Lcobucci\JWT\Token`- when you pass it to `response()->json(...)`, the `json()` method tries to `json_encode()` the object instead of using its string represenation, which will not work.

So, if you want to use the string representation of a JWT Token returned by one of the SDK's methods, you need to cast the object to a string:

```
return response()->json(["custom_token" => (string) $customToken]);
```